# Какие основные задачи bare репозитория?

Tags: git

Насколько я понял, `bare` репозиторий создается как буфер между основной копией на сервере и ветками разработки.

Но не до конца понимаю, читая статью «[удачная модель ветвления](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/)», зачем нужен этот тип репозитория, если все должно работать и так.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*bare-репозиторий* — это не какой-то особый тип репозитория. это, собственно, и есть **репозиторий**.

---

командой `git init --bare` в текущем каталоге создаётся именно репозиторий:

```
$ git init --bare
$ ls -F
branches/  config*  description  HEAD  hooks/  info/  objects/  refs/
```

---

а вот командой `git init` (без опции `--bare`) репозиторий создаётся в каталоге `.git`:

```
$ git init
$ ls -F .git
branches/  config*  description  HEAD  hooks/  info/  objects/  refs/
```

что позволяет использовать текущий каталог как *рабочий каталог* (*working dir*) с **извлечёнными** из репозитория файлами/каталогами, версии которых и отслеживаются этим самым репозиторием (вообще рабочий каталог может находиться в совершенно ином месте и указываться программе *git* с помощью опций `-C` или `--work-tree` или их комбинации (эти опции не эквивалентны), или переменной окружения `GIT_WORK_TREE`, или конфигурационной переменной `core.worktree`).

---

«превратить» *bare* в *не-bare* (и обратно) очень легко: достаточно изменить значение (`true` или `false`) переменной `bare` в секции `[core]` файла `config`. вручную или командой `git config core.bare значение`. т.е., фактически, это некий признак, на практике означающий, что «рядом есть рабочий каталог с отслеживаемыми файлами».

---

### зачем нужен этот признак?

чтобы при попытке «запушить» в текущую ветку (ту, на которую указывает содержимое файла `HEAD`) «репозитория с рабочим каталогом» (*не-bare*-репозиторий) пользователь получал ошибку и подробное объяснение:

> remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
> remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
> remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
> remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
> remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
> remote: error:
> remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
> remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
> remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless yo
> remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
> remote: error: other way.
> remote: error:
> remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
> remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'

мой вольный перевод:

> отказано в обновлении ветки `refs/heads/master`, из которой извлечены файлы в рабочий каталог.
>
> по умолчанию обновление текущей ветки в не-bare-репозитории запрещено, потому что это приведёт к несоответствию между тем, что вы «пушите», и индексом и содержимым рабочего каталога, и потребует выполнения `git reset --hard` для приведения рабочего каталога в соответствие с текущей веткой, т.е. той, которая указана в файле `HEAD`.
>
> вы можете установить значение конфигурационной переменной `receive.denyCurrentBranch` удалённого репозитория в значение `ignore` или `warn` для разрешения «пушить» в его текущую ветку; тем не менее этого не рекомендуется делать, если только вы не настроили (автоматическое) обновление рабочего каталога каким-либо иным путём.
>
> вы можете отключить выдачу этого сообщения, не меняя умолчального поведения, установив переменной `receive.denyCurrentBranch` значение `refuse`.

Answer (score 2):

Если кратко, то bare - это и есть репозиторий на сервере. Но git (в отличии от svn) децентрализованный, и серверов может быть сколько угодно. Даже на одной машине.