# Возможно ли создать на флешке репозиторий, чтобы работать с ним как с удалённым?

Tags: git

Хочется просто сделать копию, на флешке, для подстраховки, чтобы не хранить код в одном месте.

Гитхаб, или bitbucket тут не нужен, так-как работа не командная. Мне кажется, что сделать аналог удалённому репозиторию на флешке было бы удобнее.

Если это возможно, то как это реализуется?

Спасибо.

Comment: просто скопируйте каталог, да и всё.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin он не будет bare тогда.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, вы-то в курсе, что можно изменить одну строчку в файле config, и хранилище станет bare.

Comment: не относится напрямую к вопросу: чтобы управлять распределёнными файлами с помощью git, не помещая содержимое самих файлов в git (к примеру, картинки, видео, музыка итд), [можно git annex использовать](https://git-annex.branchable.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Но флешка — плохой бэкап, ее легко потерять.

Рекомендую вам посмотреть на GitLab и Bitbucket, оба сервиса предоставляют приватные (доступные только вам) репозитории на базовых бесплатных планах подписки.

Как всё-таки сделать репозиторий на флешке:

1. Сделать чистый bare-репозиторий на флешке.

   ```
   cd /path/to/flash-drive
   git init --bare reponame.git
   ```

   Появится `reponame.git`, это bare-репозиторий, в нем есть только хранилище, а файлов проекта нет, потому что они не нужны для бэкапа.
2. Подключить к нему репозиторий проекта.

   ```
   cd /path/to/project
   git remote add flashdrive /path/to/flash-drive/reponame.git
   git push flashdrive master
   ```

Answer (score 2):

скопируйте хранилище (т.е., по умолчанию, каталог `.git`) в нужное вам место под нужным вам именем, затем сделайте его [*bare*-хранилищем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542391/178576):

```
$ cp -a .git /путь/к/тому/новому/каталогу
$ git --git-dir=/путь/к/тому/новому/каталогу config core.bare true
```

---

а потом можете настроить ваше текущее хранилище на использование этого вновь созданного в качестве «удалённого» («remote») под произвольным именем (например, origin):

```
$ git remote add origin /путь/к/тому/новому/каталогу
```

и/или можете сделать ещё один клон этого нового хранилища:

```
$ git clone /путь/к/тому/новому/каталогу /путь/где/создать/клон
```