# Не получается выполнить git push

Tags: git

Не могу выполнить git push. Есть два репозитория repo1 и repo2. repo1 удаленный, repo2 локальный. Настраиваю связь между ними с помощью: `git remote add remote-repo1 /f/Denys/test/repo1`. Получаю информацию о репозитории:`git fetch remote-repo1`

Вывод после команды fetch:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 238 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
From F:/Denys/test/repo1
 * [new branch]      master     -> remote-repo1/master
```

После делаю слияние ветки мастер локального репозитория с удаленным: `git checkout --track remote-repo1/master`

Вывод поле команды checkout:
Already on 'master'
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'remote-repo1'.
Далее делаю git pull, получаю сообщение: Already up to date.
После команду git log:

```
commit 91cd7520065a2cb9f57d95c7f4f9067ee804267f (HEAD -> master, remote-repo1/master)
Author: Denys Skotarenko <skotarenkodenis@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 13 07:41:26 2020 +0200

    sdgsggs
```

Потом в repo2 создаю новый файл добавляю его в репозиторий:

```
touch file.txt
git add file.txt
 git commit -m "created file.txt"

[master fe2a825] created file.txt
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file.txt
```

смотрю, что файл добавлен:

```
$ git log
commit fe2a8253e7a6deb981e7602cb0485f41d3da7197 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Denys Skotarenko <skotarenkodenis@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 13 08:27:26 2020 +0200

    created file.txt

commit 91cd7520065a2cb9f57d95c7f4f9067ee804267f (remote-repo1/master)
Author: Denys Skotarenko <skotarenkodenis@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 13 07:41:26 2020 +0200

    sdgsggs
```

Теперь выполняю git push и получаю сообщение:

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 277 bytes | 277.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote:
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote:
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To F:/Denys/test/repo1
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'F:/Denys/test/repo1'
```

Пытался найти ответ в интернете, но так ничего внятного и не нашел. Пробовал создавать заново репозитории, перепроверял настройки, делал мердж (нашел на каком-то форуме), но ничего не помогает. Команда push не отрабатывает, хотя  с pull никаких проблем нет. Подскажите, как решить? Если выложил много лишней информации, прошу прощения, учусь с git работаю 3-й день, постарался описать максимально свои выполняемые действия.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу выполнить git push](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929376/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-git-push)

Comment: и кратакая доп. информация [про bare-хранилище](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542434/178576).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удаленный репозиторий должен быть инициализирован командой

```
git init --bare
```

Comment: Не работает. Та же ошибка. Попробовал пересоздать репозитории, результат тот же.

Comment: @DenysSkotarenko, если у вас та же самая ошибка с текстом "remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository..." и т.д. то нет, вы опять создали не bare репозиторий, а обычный. Если текста про non-bare repository нет, значит это уже другая ошибка.

Comment: @Spatz, спасибо! Разобрался!